Expected Cost of Book Selection with Varying Selection Probabilities and Position-Dependent Costs
I am working on a problem involving the expected cost of selecting books from a stack in two different ways, and I would appreciate some insights, particularly regarding the case when $m \to \infty$.
There are $n$ books in a stack, numbered from 1 to $n$, initially arranged in increasing order from top to bottom. Each book $k$ has a selection probability $p_k$, which depends on the book itself, i.e., $p_k$ is the probability of selecting the $k$-th book (not necessarily corresponding to its position in the stack). The cost of selecting the $k$-th book, when counting from the top, is $a_k$, and this cost depends on the book's position in the stack (i.e., the cost increases as the position in the stack goes down).
Two methods are used for selecting the books:

Method 1: A book is selected randomly, and then it is placed back in the same position.
Method 2: A book is selected randomly, and after selection, it is placed at the top of the stack.

I am interested in calculating the expected cost of selecting $m$ books, under both methods. For Method 1, the expected cost is straightforward, and it is given by $mN$, where
$$\displaystyle N = \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k a_k $$
This result holds because each selection is independent, and the cost per selection is the same across all selections.
However, for Method 2, the situation is more complex. After each selection, the book is placed at the top of the stack, which changes the positions of the other books, altering their associated costs in subsequent selections. I believe this introduces a random process that is more difficult to analyze, and I’m not sure how to compute the expected cost in this case. I think Markov chain will be involved.
Additionally, I would like to know what happens as $m \to \infty$. My hypothesis is that, when $p_k$ is decreasing, the expected cost for both methods should converge to the same value in the limit. I am uncertain if this is correct, so I would appreciate any insights or formal arguments to confirm or refute this.
Finally, if $a_k$ is difficult to estimate, I could approximate it as an arithmetic sequence: $a_k = a_0 + kd$. How would this assumption affect the analysis, and how could I estimate the expected cost more easily under this approximation?

I briefly tried solving it, but the fact that you can reselect books that you have already selected previously makes it harder to find an expression for the expected value of the third book. The expected cost of the first book is given by $N$, and assuming you selected the book $k_1$, then the expected cost of the second book is given by $\mathbb{E}[\text{Cost of 2nd book}] = \sum_{i=k_1+1}^{n} p_i a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k_1-1} p_i a_{i+1} + p_{k_1} a_1$.
